# Why are those two datetimes different?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, datetime

Why isn't `Time.current` equal to its parsed equivalent?

```
current = Time.current
# Wed, 16 Sep 2015 17:10:56 CEST +02:00
parsed = Time.zone.parse('16 Sep 2015 17:10:56')
# Wed, 16 Sep 2015 17:10:56 CEST +02:00
current == parsed
# false <= What ?!
current.to_i == parsed.to_i
# true
Ticket.create(datetime: current)
# ...
Ticket.find_by_datetime(parsed)
# nil  <= Why ?!
```

I'm actually having trouble with this in a Ruby on Rails application where I try to find a record based on a datetime attribute that has been parsed, like shown on the last lines.

I really don't get it. Time zones are the same, times are the same down to seconds. What's happening here?

Moreover, how should I proceed to find a record based on a parsed datetime?

Comment: Your computer clock probably has sub-second precision ;-) (hint: `to_f`)

Comment: Thanks !

Okay so the parsed datetime doesn't have sub-second precision. But then what should I do to fetch the record in the database ?

Comment: Either truncate the attribute to whole seconds before saving it to the database or pass a range that covers the whole second: `Ticket.where(datetime: parsed...parsed+1)`

Comment: For @Stefan's truncating tip: `current.change(:usec => 0)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help. I hope you don't mind but since pieces of the final answer are scattered across multiple answers I will answer my own question building on what you all said.

So as for why the dates are different, it's because of the milliseconds missing in the parsed datetime. As @dimakura mentioned.

```
current.to_f #=> 1442417032.6567826
parsed.to_f  #=> 1442417032.0
```

Then the answer about how could we fetch the Ticket record based a the parsed datetime.

First it's important to know this will be relevant only for PostgreSQL (my case) or other databases that actually store milliseconds. Thanks to @sjagr for mentioning this.

So we have to query for a range from parsed to parsed + 1 second, like @Stefan explained:

```
Ticket.where(datetime: parsed...parsed+1).first
```

And if we have control on the Ticket creation, we could also remove the millisecond precision before saving the the database. Thanks to @sjagr for providing an easy way to do that.

```
current = Time.current
Ticket.create(datetime: current.change(usec: 0))
```

Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 21):

They should not be the same:

```
current.to_f #=> 1442417032.6567826
parsed.to_f  #=> 1442417032.0
```

When parsing, you miss milliseconds.

Comment: Could you then expand on how we can fetch a record in the DB based on a parsed string that doesn't have millisecond precision ?

Comment: @JeremyF. Can you print `ticket.datetime.to_f`?

Comment: So it's not exactly what you get just from "seconds"

Comment: I wonder if you fetched the entry later, would it include those milliseconds? @JeremyF. What is your backlining database technology? MySQL certainly wouldn't store milliseconds, whereas PostgreSQL would.

Comment: Good guess it's PostgreSQL and does indeed store the milliseconds as well.

Comment: For even more precision have a look at `current.subsec`.

Comment: @JeremyF. - In the vast majority of the cases, if you have to parse a string when retrieving a date/time from a database, you're doing it wrong.  You should be concerned with data type mapping, not string parsing.

Comment: @MattJohnson Good point, but here I don't really have a choice I'm dealing with external data. Thanks for raising this idea in my brain though,  it will be useful next time :)

Comment: @JeremyF. Doing an "equals" comparison on timestamps is pretty much never a good idea anyway, for that matter. Equals on a timestamp truncated to date only or midnight of its date (*after* being localized to a particular time zone)? Sometimes that's okay. But almost any other case, you want an in-range comparison.

Comment: @sjagr just a side note, MySQL does support milliseconds as of 5.6.4

Answer (score 3):

It's because they are not equal, they differ by parts of the second. What you see in the console is the result of `inspect` method called on those dates, which by default, drop any sub-second parts.